# Not able to use Vue JS via CDN file inside Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, firefox-addon, content-security-policy

I am trying to create a Firefox extension and have it ready in Vue JS. I am using the Production CDN version of Vue JS from [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html)

This is what my manifest.json looks like:

```
{
"name": "This is a test",
"description": "Test",
"version": "1.0.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"browser_action": {
    "browser_style": true,
    "default_title": "This is a test"
},
"permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab", "https://test.com/*"],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["./js/background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["*://*.test.com/*", "*://test.com/*"],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "all_frames": false,
        "js": ["./js/contentscript.js"]
    }
],
"icons": {
    "48": "./images/logo.png"
},
"browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
        "id": "addon@test.com",
        "strict_min_version": "98.0"
    }
}
```

When I try to import it in Firefox, I receive the error: Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at eval (“script-src”). inside vue.js file.

I am importing the vue.js file (downloaded from vue's website) inside the index.html file using normal script tags.

I am trying to create a Firefox extension and have it ready in Vue JS. I am using the Production CDN version of Vue JS from [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html)

This is what my manifest.json looks like:

```
{
"name": "This is a test",
"description": "Test",
"version": "1.0.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"browser_action": {
    "browser_style": true,
    "default_title": "This is a test"
},
"permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab", "https://test.com/*"],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["./js/background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["*://*.test.com/*", "*://test.com/*"],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "all_frames": false,
        "js": ["./js/contentscript.js"]
    }
],
"icons": {
    "48": "./images/logo.png"
},
"browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
        "id": "addon@test.com",
        "strict_min_version": "98.0"
    }
}
```

When I try to import it in Firefox, I receive the error: Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at eval (“script-src”). inside vue.js file.

I am importing the vue.js file (downloaded from vue's website) inside the index.html file using normal script tags.

Comment: I wonder the error stating something about [content_security_policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy) is a clue